# Сортировка отрезков встроенными сортировками в С++

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, stl

На вход подаётся некоторое количество отрезков,каждый из которых задаётся левой и правой границей. Возможно ли как-нибудь отсортировать именно отрезки(две границы вместе) по правой границе, используя встроенные сортировки sort()/qsort(). Пытался что-нибудь сделать с помощью указателей и динамических массивов, но ничего не вышло. 
Я понимаю как это реализовать самому сделав сортировки, но нужно получить как можно меньше кода с моей стороны, поэтому захотелось воспользоваться стандартными сортировками.

Comment: Поясните на примере, как вы хотите сортировать отрезки, и как они сами задаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, как можно сортировать отрезки по второму значению и при этом обеспечить, что при равных вторых значениях будут упорядочены первые значения отрезков.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> a[] = 
    {
        { 1, 3 }, { 4, 2 }, { 6, 5 }, { 0, 2 }, { 4, 5 }
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        [](const auto &a, const auto &b) 
        { 
            return std::tie( a.second, a.first ) < std::tie( b.second, b.first ); 
        });

    for (const auto &p : a)
    {
        std::cout << "<" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "> ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
<0, 2> <4, 2> <1, 3> <4, 5> <6, 5>
```

Если не важно, как будут упорядочены первые значения отрезков, то функциональный объект для сортировки может быть упрощен

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> a[] = 
    {
        { 1, 3 }, { 4, 2 }, { 6, 5 }, { 0, 2 }, { 4, 5 }
    };

    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        [](const auto &a, const auto &b) 
        { 
            return a.second < b.second; 
        });

    for (const auto &p : a)
    {
        std::cout << "<" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "> ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
<4, 2> <0, 2> <1, 3> <6, 5> <4, 5>
```

Можете заметить разницу между выводами этих двух программ.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я ещё только разбираюсь в стандартных контейнерах. Ваш ответ полностью удовлетворил.